# SwiftUI - Add gradient at the end of the list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, linear-gradients

I would like to add linear gradient at the end of the list to show there are more rows below. I did add code for it, but the gradient shows in the center of the list.

How do I move it below? I added alignment to bottom, but that didn't work either.

Note: I have too much of code, so I have added pieces of it, but the gradient logic is exactly what I have in the code. Let me know incase if you want a perfect code.

***Code:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.someCustomView.padding(.top, 10.0)
            self.directionsList
            self.endButton.padding(.top, 5.0).padding(.bottom, 15.0)
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.gray)
    }


    private var directionsList: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                let displaySteps: [DirectionSteps] = [] // objects of custom type DirectionSteps
                if !displaySteps.isEmpty {
                    List(displaySteps, id: \.self) { detail in
                        HStack {

                        }
                        .id(detail.directionIndex)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.lightGray)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20.0)
                } else {
                    Color.clear
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, -20.0)
            .mask(
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.black)
                    LinearGradient(
                        stops: [
                            Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.17, blue: 0.18), location: 0.00),
                            Gradient.Stop(color: Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.17, blue: 0.18).opacity(0), location: 1.00)
                        ],
                        startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1),
                        endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
                    )
                }.frame(alignment: .bottom)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
        .mask(
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.black.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                LinearGradient(
                    stops: [
                        Gradient.Stop(color: .black, location: 0.00),
                        Gradient.Stop(color: .black.opacity(0), location: 1.00)
                    ],
                    startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0),
                    endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
                )
                .frame(height: 100)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

In this example, the `Color.black` takes up all available space and then you can set the height of your gradient using the last `frame` modifier.

[image]